# Unable to find definition of dict in python repo

Tags: python, module

I'm not too good with Python, and I'm trying to find some source code associated with torchvision (https://github.com/pytorch/vision/tree/main/torchvision/).

I saw the following lines of code:

```
from torchvision.models import models
models.__dict__["alexnet"](first=True, second=False).eval()
```

I know that `torchvision.models` corresponds to this directory: https://github.com/pytorch/vision/tree/main/torchvision/models

But I am having trouble figuring out where `__dict__` is defined. It doesn't appear to be in the above directory after I tried to grep for its definition. Where or how can I find its definition?

Answer (score 0):

`__dict__` is a predefined variable in python. When a class is created, the data in that class is stored in `__dict__`.

Comment: Ahh I see, but `models` here is a directory and not a class?

Comment: I should edit, in almost any data type that can store multiple items, with names for those items(besides `dict`), `__dict___` is present,and `models` is a subpackage, similar to a package.

Answer (score 0):

`__dict__` is built into Python classes.

```
class P:
    def __init__(self)
        self.v = 'hello'

p = P()

print(p.__dict__)
```